# Xcode 11.4.1 breakpoint not working for pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, breakpoints

i have downloaded xcode 11.4.1 and now break points which set on pod's class not working, previously it was working in older version of xcode. How to enable breakpoint for this version of xcode 11.4.1.

Comment: Hi, I the breakpoints in Xcode 11.4.1 works for me, by default. Maybe, there are other things caused your issue.

Comment: Maybe you're running your code with optimisations ON. Disable optimisations in your build settings (Swift Compiler - Code Generation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, dont waste much time if u do changes in pod files and never affect. Just do clean Build Folder and it will affect all the changes applied to pods.